# Поиск похожих описаний товаров

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В общем появилась задачка на подумать. Реализовать могу и сам, а вот реализовать то что... Кучу вариантов передумал, и везде одно и то же, слишком медленно, или слишком дыряво.

В общем в таблице продуктов (MySQL `products`), есть товар, у него есть поле `title`, в котором примерно записано следующее:

> Сервер Dell PowerEdge R430 (210-ADLO-172)<1xE5-2650v4 1x16Gb 2RRD x8
>   2.5" RW H730 iD8En+PC 1G 4P 1x550W>

Есть таблица похожих продуктов `ws_products`, в которой есть поля `art`, `title`, `description`. Среди похожих продуктов, находится товар, имеющий примерно похожие название (`Dell R430`), номер (скажем `210.ADLO.172`), описание (описание к примеру более развернутое, но так же присутствуют фразы `16GB H730 550W`). Всё, больше ничего, никаких ключевых слов, оформления у товаров абсолютно разные.

Задача взять товар из таблицы похожей продукции и найти максимально похожий товар из таблицы оригиналов, или близкий к оригиналу

Сам пытался делать все через `like`, предварительно разбивая строку на целые слова без спец-символов (заменял на пробелы, брал слова больше чем два символа), и искал список всех похожих. Потом проходился по ним, брал шинглы, сравнивал размеры `crc32`, сортировал в порядке убывания кандидатов (по проценту вхождения одинаковых кусков), и получалась белиберда в общем, очень долго, товаров тьмень, что там, что там, и вешал в итоге сервак такими махинациями...

Пытался заюзать Сфинкс, и не вышло, строки изначально не разбиты, не имеют одинаковых оформлений, что в первой таблице, что во второй. По итогу нужны `matches` слов, цитат, не получилось разобраться, может я дурак...

Может есть у кого идея, как лучше всего это реализовать? Или если есть пример какой, особенно для Сфинкса, если он лучше подойдет к моей задаче.

Comment: Я бы попробовал создать отдельно таблицу с ключевыми словами, куда добавлял части названий как unique (банально разрезал по пробелу, перевел в нижний регистр и отфильтровал часть мусора по стоп-словам, короткие слова и т.д.). Затем создал еще одну таблицу (для связи many-many), где бы хранил id товаров и id ключевых слов. При обновлении названий товаров или их добавлении, обновлял ключевые слова и связывал с товаром, при необходимости создавал новые - как правило, это легко реализовать. Для поиска похожих товаров брал бы те, у кого больше всего совпало ключевых слов, все работало бы быстро.

Comment: Представьте, у меня 600т товаров в данный момент в одной таблице, и 200т в другой, ключевые слова во второй таблице, увы, мне никто не заполнит, да и в первой тоже самое. Так бы с радостью...

Comment: не вижу проблем, скрипт сделает это за несколько минут

Comment: Хммм, я пропустил центр вашего комментария. Интересная задумка

Comment: "найти максимально похожий товар" - вы так самого главного и не написали. По каким критериям определять, что товар максимально похожим?

Comment: вырезаем все, кроме букв и цифр, бьем по пробелу, сортируем. А потом а-ля левенштейн, только не для букв, а для слов

Answer (score 0):

Никакие "текстовые" алгоритмы вам не помогу в этой задаче. Нужно использовать людей, а точнее своих клиентов.
Если у вас есть табличка похожих товаров, то значит, где-то эти товары выводятся и, соответсвенно, есть переходы с товара на похожие товары. Вам просто нужно трекать эти переходы и соответственно товар на который больше всего переходов из задано и есть максимально похожим.

Answer (score -1):

Для этих целей,я думаю, специальная функция PHP [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php) Единственно все упирается в быстродействие. Я бы посадил некий скрипт на крон, который для всех новых записей будет искать похожие. Т.е. определяем некую заданную степень похожести и погнали по всему списку. Нашли товар - записали в специальную таблицу эту пару. Таким образом и у старого товара добавится похожий и у нового они будут

Answer (score -2):

Я когда то решал чем похожую задачу, и решил через `levenshtein` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php.

Получайте все нужные поля товаров, склеивайте их в нужном порядке и сравнивайте с искомой строкой, у кого будет наименьшее расстояние Левенштейна - тот и наиболее похож.

Я конечно не знаю сколько там у вас товаров, поэтому архитектурно что-то посоветовать не могу, через крон это делать или как то еще. Проведите тесты и на их основании уже работайте дальше.

Comment: левенштейн не даст результата от слова совсем на задаче поиска маркеров в разнодлинных строках со случайным порядком вхождения этих маркеров